# how do I make jquery scrollbar plugin dynamic so that it is applied to content loaded even after dom?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've discovered this beautiful plugin: http://www.nikolaydyankov.com/lionbars/ for adding fancy scrollbars to anything!

Problem I'm having is that if I use lionbars plugin on static content it works fine. But my real life need for this is a bit more complicated than that.

Another jquery plugin loads div (where scrollbar is required) when user inputs some data in a field. So div doesn't exist when lionbars is trying add scroll.

Is there a way to change this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.ac_results ul').lionbars();
});
```

into something that listens to the page content all the time and applies fancy scrollbar when needed?

Is there any other way? I was thinking maybe I should add $('.ac_results ul').lionbars(); ad the end of [the other plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/autocompleter/) I use to generate div?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like JQuery's live method. Unless the LionBar plugin has a live (or equivalent) method, then your only option is to trigger the `$('.ac_results ul').lionbars();` after the dynamic content has loaded (as you guessed).